# WEEK_OF_MONTH returns 0 while linux command returns 1

Tags: java, linux, date, calendar, debian

For some weird reason.. `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)` returns `0`, while command in linux returns `1`

```
root@ns4009576:~# echo $((($(date +%d)-1)/7+1))
```

> 1

In the beginning i thought it could be that first day is Monday, so Sunday (today) is month 0 (?)
but that doesn't seem to be the case either, locale returns Sunday as first day

```
root@ns4009576:~# locale day
```

> Sunday;Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday;Saturday

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why are you comparing the result of a java method and a linux command ?

Comment: You better print out some details about your calendar like `System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance());`

Answer (score 0):

Java may not respect the same locale rules as your `date` command. Comparing the two is probably not a great idea.

You are getting `0` as the week of the month because Sunday is not defined as your first day of the week. Try adding this to your code to see the difference:

```
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
```